# Why webjobs api always returns "Accepted" status not 200 Ok

Tags: c#, api, azure, webjob

I am trying to run my azure web jobs through c# code but it works but it's return accepted status with 202 status code.

I am using below code for the same code snippet for webjob api call from web app.

[image: Code snippet for webjob api call from web app]

Comment: Instead of screenshot of the code, please include actual code in question.

Comment: Because a 200 would signal the job executed fine, while 202 would just indicate "okay, I hear you, let me see what I can do for you".

Comment: A WebJob could potentially run for like half an hour. Azure would kill the connection before a response is sent.

Comment: You could show more code ,then we can test it or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may doubt that the HTTP response status code should be `200 OK`, not `202 Accepted` if a HTTP requst have been handled successfully. However, either `200 OK` or `202 Accepted` is legal and reasonable, please refer to the 10 section [`10 Status Code Definitions`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) of W3C RFC-2616 to know them in depth, as below.

> 10.2.1 **200 OK** The request has succeeded. The information returned with the response is dependent on the method used in the request, for
>   example:
>
> GET an entity corresponding to the requested resource is sent in the
>   response;
>
> HEAD the entity-header fields corresponding to the requested resource
>   are sent in the response without any message-body;
>
> POST an entity describing or containing the result of the action;
>
> TRACE an entity containing the request message as received by the end
>   server.
>
> 10.2.3 **202 Accepted** The request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed. The request might or might not
>   eventually be acted upon, as it might be disallowed when processing
>   actually takes place. There is no facility for re-sending a status
>   code from an asynchronous operation such as this.
>
> The 202 response is intentionally non-committal. Its purpose is to
>   allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a
>   batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without
>   requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until
>   the process is completed. The entity returned with this response
>   SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and
>   either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user
>   can expect the request to be fulfilled.

Meanwhile, two code comments below from GitHub Kudu repo explain why used `202 Accepted` for triggering webjobs in here.

I. [Kudu.Services/ServiceHookHandlers/FetchHandler.cs#L111](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/a13592e6654585d5c2ee5c6a05fa39fa812ebb84/Kudu.Services/ServiceHookHandlers/FetchHandler.cs#L111)

```
// Return a http 202: the request has been accepted for processing, but the processing has not been completed.
```

II. [Kudu.Services/Jobs/JobsController.cs#L191](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/a13592e6654585d5c2ee5c6a05fa39fa812ebb84/Kudu.Services/Jobs/JobsController.cs#L191)

```
// Return a 200 in the ARM case, otherwise a 202 can cause it to poll on /run, which we don't support
// For non-ARM, stay with the 202 to reduce potential impact of change
```

It's up to the design intent of services.